# Android custom permission vs app signature

Tags: android, android-permissions, signature, android-signing

I have gone through the available documentation and SO posts on both these topics (custom permissions and app signature), my understanding is:

1. Apps signed with same key can use signature-level permissions
2. A custom permission should only be defined in one place and the app declaring the permission needs to be installed first
3. A custom permission can be defined in multiple apps if the apps share same signature

Now I need to define some components in one app that I will be using in another app signed with the same key, but according to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining#custom-recommendations) I don't need to define a custom permission and can place a signature check

> If the functionality is only available to apps signed with the same signature as the providing app, you may be able to avoid defining custom permissions by using signature checks. When one of your apps makes a request of another of your apps, the second app can verify that both apps are signed with the same certificate before complying with the request.

I don't understand what is meant by signature checks, is there a way to place a check in manifest on that component or do I have to check it programmatically? If latter, isn't it better to define a custom permission in both apps instead (to negate installation order issue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to place a check in manifest on that component

No, sorry.

> do I have to check it programmatically?

Yes. [This pair of old projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/SigCheck) demonstrate a bound service and a client that checks the signature of the service. Those projects are covered in a chapter in a chapter of [this free old book](https://commonsware.com/Android/). That sample has problems in modern Android, as an app can have multiple signatures. But, the [`SiganturesUtil` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/SignatureUtils.java) that it relies on shows how to get signatures from `PackageManager` for an installed app. You can then compare them with the expected value to determine if you are indeed talking to the app that you expect.

> If latter, isn't it better to define a custom permission in both apps instead (to negate installation order issue)?

Signature checks are more flexible — they are not limited to two apps being signed by the same signing key. That, plus historical issues with custom permissions, may be why Google recommends signature checks over custom permissions on that page.